# Remove table row doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove a table row (tr) from a table with a form inside. I'm using this function to do it.

```
$('.removeStop').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeTo(400, 0, function () { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
    return false;
});
```

The fadeTo works fine, but when it goes to remove the row, it goes to the remove function, it goes into an infinite loop "cannot remove undefined".

Maybe it's just some stupid error I made, but I would think if it can fade the whole row, it should be able to remove the same thing.

Any help would be great :)

Edit: Here is the HTML:

```
<tr align="left">
                <td width="100">School: </td>
                <td>
                    <select name="stops[school][0][studentid]" class="combobox" style="display: none; ">
                    <option value="">Select a school...</option>
                    <option value="1" selected="selected">Hogwarts School of Wizardry</option><option value="2">Itchy and Scratchy Land</option><option value="3">Springfield Elementary</option>                       </select><input class="ui-autocomplete-input ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-corner-right inputCustom" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true">
                </td>
                <td width="70"></td>
                <td width="100">Time (24hr): </td>
                                    <td><input class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-corner-right inputCustom" value="15" name="stops[school][0][hr]" style="width:50px;" type="text"> <input class="ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-left ui-corner-right inputCustom" value="01" name="stops[school][0][min]" style="width:50px;" type="text"></td>
                <td><a href="#" class="removeStop">Remove</a></td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: It works here. http://jsfiddle.net/d2Ccr/2/

Comment: Can you show us the html code as well?

Comment: Sorry about that, there is the HTML :)

Comment: Source of problem could be different. I've tried your code with all major browsers and there are no errors.

Comment: Here is a pastebin of my complete js file http://pastebin.com/ipvLk5Hj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.removeStop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').fadeOut(400, function () { 
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: This removes the row, but it still goes into an undefined loop for some reason... after it's removed.

Comment: @adamzwakk: What's the undefined loop? You mean infinite loop? Do you have some other code, which interacts with `tr` elements?

Comment: Yeah the infinite loop. "Cannot call method of 'remove' of undefined"

I have a link to add rows too, but that's it.

Comment: @adamzwakk: **[There is nor undefined or infinite loop, neither  "Cannot call method of 'remove' of undefined" for me](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/VxvGM/)**? Share the JavaScript code you have, maybe the problem relies there.

Comment: Maybe it's because of the widget I have? Here's a pastebin of my entire JS file: http://pastebin.com/ipvLk5Hj

Comment: The problem is with `this.button.remove();` inside the `destroy()` method. I have commented that out and **[everything works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/VxvGM/)**. I have cleaned up your code a little bit, you don't need to do `$(function(){})` inside `$(document).ready()`, because they are the same thing.

Comment: It works! Thanks. I knew about the $function(){}) thing, I was just going to clean everything up when the site was done. :)

Thanks again!